# Use only part of a DB when iterating ASP.net - iterating through the whole DB slows it way down

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, loops

[image][image]I'm a brand new programmer and am stuck - hoping for advice.

I have a program through ASP.net. It works great until the DB gets about 100 entries and then it gets really slow.

I know the reason but don't know how to fix it.

The program allows employees of a large 911 dispatch center to sign up for breaks, lunches and restroom breaks from their consoles. They select their names and position from dropdowns. It adds the info to a DB when they click submit. The program then iterates through the DB to find the active breaks / lunches / restroom breaks to find the active ones and displays them in a table.

It's important that the table update quickly when someone goes on a list so everyone from all consoles knows when someone adds to that table. So I have the program iterating through the db every 5 seconds to update who's on what list. It's happy with less than 100 entries but it doesn't do well with more - which makes sense - that's a lot to iterate through in such a little time frame.

I had two possible ideas but I don't know how to make them work and the Google isn't helping much.

One thought was just to import data from just the past two days and have it just iterate through that. Without iterating like I have it now, I'm not sure how to get it to do that.

Another thought I had was to save everything into a list at the same time it saves to the DB so it iterates just through memory and not a DB. I don't know how to store multiple fields into that list, though. Maybe a dictionary? I don't know. I don't know how practical that is.

Here's some of the code:

Controller:

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateLunch(Lunch lunch)
    {
        try
        {
            lunch.TimeEntered = DateTime.Now;
            db.Lunches.Add(lunch);
            db.SaveChanges();

            var breaksList = db.Breaks.ToList();
            foreach (var item in breaksList)
            {
                Break mdl = new Break();
                mdl.BreakID = item.BreakID;
                mdl.Employee = item.Employee;
                mdl.TimeEntered = item.TimeEntered;
                mdl.TimeCleared = item.TimeCleared;
                mdl.PositionID = item.PositionID;
                mdl.EmpSent = item.EmpSent;
                if (db.Breaks != null)
                {
                    db.Breaks.Add(mdl);
                }
                db.Breaks.Add(mdl);
            }
            var employee = db.Employees.ToList();
            foreach (var item in employee)
            {
                Employee mdl = new Employee();
                mdl.EmployeeID = item.EmployeeID;
                mdl.FirstName = item.FirstName;
                mdl.LastName = item.LastName;
                mdl.NotActive = item.NotActive;
                mdl.Force = item.Force;
                mdl.DisplayName = item.DisplayName;
                if (db.Employees != null)
                {
                    db.Employees.Add(mdl);
                }
            }
            var dthmodel = db.Dths.ToList();
            foreach (var item in dthmodel)
            {
                Dth mdl = new Dth();
                mdl.DthID = item.DthID;
                mdl.Employee = item.Employee;
                mdl.TimeCleared = item.TimeCleared;
                mdl.TimeEntered = item.TimeEntered;
                mdl.PositionID = item.PositionID;
                mdl.EmpSent = item.EmpSent;
                if (db.Dths != null)
                {
                    db.Dths.Add(mdl);
                }
            }

            var lunchModel = db.Lunches.OrderBy(x => x.LunchTime);
            foreach (var item in lunchModel)
            {
                Lunch mdl = new Lunch();
                mdl.Employee = item.Employee;
                mdl.LunchID = item.LunchID;
                mdl.PositionID = item.PositionID;
                mdl.LunchTime = item.LunchTime;
                mdl.LongerLunch = item.LongerLunch;
                mdl.Double = item.Double;
                mdl.TimeEntered = item.TimeEntered;
                mdl.EmpSent = item.EmpSent;
                mdl.TimeCleared = item.TimeCleared;
                if (db.Lunches != null)
                {
                    db.Lunches.Add(mdl);
                }
            }
            var positionModel = db.Positions.ToList();
            foreach (var item in positionModel)
            {
                Position mdl = new Position();
                mdl.PositionID = item.PositionID;
                mdl.PositionName = item.PositionName;
                if (db.Positions != null)
                {
                    db.Positions.Add(mdl);
                }
            }

            var date = DateTime.Now;
            var dateOffset = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
            ViewBag.EmployeesNames = db.Employees.Where(x => x.NotActive == false).OrderBy(x => x.DisplayName).ToList();
            ViewBag.PositionNames = db.Positions.ToList();
            ViewBag.LunchTimes = db.Lunches.Where(x => x.TimeEntered <= date && x.TimeEntered >= dateOffset).OrderBy(x => x.LunchTime).ToList();
            ViewBag.positionOrdered = db.Positions.OrderBy(m => m.PositionName).ToList();
            ViewBag.Dths = db.Dths.Where(x => x.TimeEntered <= date && x.TimeEntered >= dateOffset).ToList();
            ViewBag.Breaks = db.Breaks.Where(x => x.TimeEntered <= date && x.TimeEntered >= dateOffset).ToList();
            ViewBag.Lunches = db.Lunches.Where(x => x.TimeEntered <= date && x.TimeEntered >= dateOffset).ToList();
            ViewBag.breakOffFloor = db.Breaks.Where(x => x.EmpSent == true && x.TimeCleared == null && (x.TimeEntered <= date && x.TimeEntered >= dateOffset)).ToList();
            ViewBag.dthOffFloor = db.Dths.Where(x => x.EmpSent == true && x.TimeCleared == null && (x.TimeEntered <= date && x.TimeEntered >= dateOffset)).ToList();
            ViewBag.lunchOffFloor = db.Lunches.Where(x => x.EmpSent == true && x.TimeCleared == null && (x.TimeEntered <= date && x.TimeEntered >= dateOffset)).ToList();

            string partialHtml = Common.RenderRazorViewToString(ControllerContext, "~/Views/Home/_DropDowns.cshtml");
            return Json(new { success = true, html = partialHtml }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { success = false });
        }
    }
```

Index:

```
var employee = ViewBag.EmployeesNames;
    var positionNames = ViewBag.PositionNames;
    var modelOrdered = ViewBag.LunchTimes;
    var positionOrdered = ViewBag.positionOrdered;
    var breakOffFloor = ViewBag.breakOffFloor;
    var dthOffFloor = ViewBag.dthOffFloor;
    var lunchOffFloor = ViewBag.lunchOffFloor;

<div class="card" id="Dropdowns" style="width: 12.5em; margin-left: .5em; position:absolute">
    <div class="card-body" id="refresh-card" style="margin-right:3em; margin-left:-.5em">
        <h5 class="card-title " style="text-align:center; display:inline-block; margin-left:3em">DTH     <img src="~/Content/Images/question.jpg" height="15" width="15" 
            data-toggle="popover" title="@DTHquestion"/></h5>
        <table class="table-bordered" style="width:10em;">
            @*populate the table with only those breaks that lack a TimeCleared value*@
            @if (ViewBag.Dths != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in ViewBag.Dths)
                {
                    if (item.TimeCleared == null)
                    {
                        if (item.TimeEntered.AddMinutes(1) > DateTime.Now)
                        {
                            if (item.EmpSent == false)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    @*Make each name clickable to set a TimeCleared datetime.Now time*@
                                    <td class="listTime">
                                        <input type="hidden" class="hiddenDthID" value="@item.DthID" />
                                        <a href="Javascript:;" class="empNameDth" style="color:black">@item.Employee.DisplayName</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="listTime" style="width:2.5em">
                                        @item.Position.PositionName
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="listTime" style="width:1.5em; text-align:center">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="dthSent" value="@item.EmpSent" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                            if (item.EmpSent == true)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    @*Make each name clickable to set a TimeCleared datetime.Now time*@
                                    <td class="empSentGreen">
                                        <input type="hidden" class="hiddenDthID" value="@item.DthID" />
                                        <a href="Javascript:;" class="empNameDth" style="color:black">@item.Employee.DisplayName</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="empSentGreen" style="width:2.5em">
                                        @item.Position.PositionName
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="empSentGreen" style="width:1.5em; text-align:center">
                                        <img height="13" width="13" src="~/Content/Images/disabledcheck.jpg" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (item.EmpSent == false)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    @*Make each name clickable to set a TimeCleared datetime.Now time*@
                                    <td class="DthIdNumber">
                                        <input type="hidden" class="hiddenDthID" value="@item.DthID" />
                                        <a href="Javascript:;" class="empNameDth" style="color:black">@item.Employee.DisplayName</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="DthIdNumber" style="width:2.5em">
                                        @item.Position.PositionName
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="DthIdNumber" style="width:1.5em; text-align:center">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="dthSent" value="@item.EmpSent" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                            if (item.EmpSent == true)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    @*Make each name clickable to set a TimeCleared datetime.Now time*@
                                    <td class="DthIdNumber" style="background-color:lightgreen">
                                        <input type="hidden" class="hiddenDthID" value="@item.DthID" />
                                        <a href="Javascript:;" class="empNameDth" style="color:black">@item.Employee.DisplayName</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="DthIdNumber" style="width:2.5em;background-color:lightgreen">
                                        @item.Position.PositionName
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="DthIdNumber" style="width:1.5em; background-color:lightgreen;text-align:center">
                                        <img height="13" width="13" src="~/Content/Images/disabledcheck.jpg" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        </table>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a scope of optimization in the code shared by you. But that won't solve your underlying problem.
The real problem is not the code but bad database design and poor approach towards the problem.

I would suggest you to keep only one table for the lunch details. say (LUNCH_DETAILS)

Based on above shared problem, the structure would look something like this:

```
ID (Primary Key)  PostionId EmployeeId  TimeEntered  TimeCleares IsAvailable  ...others
101               10           1001           12:30       01:00      Y        .........
102               11           1002           12:40                  N        .........
```

Now any time any employee visits the canteen to have their lunch, you would only do one insert in above table and based on `IsAvailable`  column you can tell if a postion (with `PostionId` ) is currently available or not.

With this approach there will only be one insert operation and no need to iterate to any data.

Comment: Thank you! I think we're on the same page but I don't think I explained myself well. There's one entry per lunch that gets updated. When a lunch is created, there's one entry that updates. TimeEntered is stamped at creation. When they leave for lunch, the EmpSent bool sets to true. When they come back, the TimeCleared gets stamped - all in one entry. I attached a pic so you can see how my table looks. The problem is in the next pic. To populate that table in the UI I iterate. If TimeEntered != null but TimeCleared == null, show it. If EmpSent True, green, etc. That iteration is my bottleneck.